# how to get value out of v-for loop in <select> and <option>

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am looking for a way to get a value out of a v-for loop. Can anyone help me with this?
I have the following code:

```
Select Country:
        <select @change="selectCountryStats(country.code)">
            <option
                v-for="country in everyCountry"
                :key="country.name"
                value="country.name"
                
            >
                {{ country.name }}
            </option>
        </select>
```

and in @change I would like to get the value of `country.code`, but this value is first known, when the v-for loop is triggered, which is not the case.

Any solution for this problem will be appreaciated.

Comment: Use v-model="variable" where model variable will hold the current value of select and then call `selectCountryStats()` on change without parameters and get value by `this.variable` also you will need to put option value as country or country.code instead of name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `v-for`'s iterator outside of the `v-for` loop because it's out of scope.

For the `change`-event handler to receive the country code, you'd have to change the `<option>.value` bindings from `country.name` to `country.code`:

```html
<option :value="country.code">
```

For [inline event handlers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers), the event parameter is stored in a special `$event` variable. And since the `change` event's target is the `<select>`, you could access the new value (the country code of the selection) in the `change`-event handler via `$event.target.value`:

```html
<select @change="selectCountryStats($event.target.value)">
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    everyCountry: [
      {
        name: 'United States',
        code: 'US'
      },
      {
        name: 'Canada',
        code: 'CA'
      },
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    selectCountryStats(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select @change="selectCountryStats($event.target.value)">
    <option
            v-for="country in everyCountry"
            :key="country.name"
            :value="country.code"

            >
      {{ country.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```